# dependencyManagement for dependency with <classifier> and without it

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jboss, guava

I'm using guava in a few modules in my application.
I was deploying this application on Tomcat, so I used this dependency in my modules

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now I need to deploy this application on Tomcat and on JBoss. For JBoss I need to use this same dependency with `<classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I was thinking about using profiles in my root pom.xml for example

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>tomcat</id>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                    <version>${guava.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                    <version>${guava.version}</version>
                    <classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now when I run `mvn clean install -Ptomcat` projects builds successfully, but when I run `mvn clean install -Pjboss` I get exception:

```
The project [...] has 1 error 'dependencies.dependency.version'
for com.google.guava:guava:jar is missing.
```

I think that this error is caused because I need to change in all my modules

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>tomcat</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Is there a simpler way to make that this project will run on Tomcat and on JBoss? Now I need to duplicate this same code in all modules where guava is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you defined `${guava.version}`? Look for `<properties>` in pom.xml:

```xml
<properties>
    <guava.version>15.0</guava.version>
    <!-- another project properties here -->
</properties>
```

Also, [current version of Guava (16.0.1 as of writing this answer) is CDI agnostic](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1527#c20), and thus you should use simple dependency declaration without need for distinct profiles for Tomcat / JBoss or use of `cdi1.0` classifier:

```xml
<properties>
    <guava.version>16.0.1</guava.version>
    <!-- another project properties here -->
</properties>

<!-- <dependencies> -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>${guava.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

P.S. `<classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>` is available **only** in Guava 15.0 ([as a bug workaround](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1527#c16)), so if you're stuck on 15.0 for some reason you should probably not be using `${guava.version}` but rather hardcode `<version>15.0</version>`...

Comment: Yes, I was using `<guava.version>15.0</guava.version>` After upgrading to 16.0.1 everything works fine.

Is there a solution to my problem if the issue would apply to other library (not guava version 15.0)? Or only solution is to use different profiles in all sub modules for dependency with `<classifier>` and without?

Comment: So your [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is solved and profiles + dependencies works fine (just checked). That said, I don't think there's easier solution for that, profiles + dependencies is IMO the way to go.